# How to create wordpress like functions in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, function

To pass variables into functions, I do the following (as other people I'm sure):

```
function addNums($num1, $num2)
{
    $num1 + $num2;
}

addNums(2, 2);
```

My question is how would I structure a function to act like Wordpress:

```
wp_list_categories('title_li=');
```

Essentially I am looking for a way to create a key/value pair in my functions.
Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for something like "return $array[$param1] = $param2;"? Sorry not a wordpress expert.. Btw. I would suggest giving each parameter a distinct name!

Comment: I don't know if that addNums example would work correctly...

Comment: Here is a link to the API for wp_list_categories() http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories

Comment: I don't know anything about WP but wouldn't it make sense to just pass actual PHP arrays into functions?  You have a built-in data type that supports collections of key/value pairs.  Alternately, you could easily look at the WP code to figure out how they do it.

Comment: In my answer below I point to an online copy of the WP source: http://phpxref.com/xref/wordpress/wp-includes/category-template.php.source.html#l425

Comment: Also, the reason for using a string like this would be to allow named variables in a compact manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [parse_str](http://php.net/parse_str) to parse the string for arguments. The tricky thing is that you may not want to just allow any and all parameters to get passed in. So here's an example of only allowing certain parameters to be used when they're passed in.

In the following example, only `foo`, `bar` and `valid` would be allowed.

```
function exampleParseArgs($arg_string) {
    // for every valid argument, include in
    // this array with "true" as a value
    $valid_arguments = array(
        'foo' => true,
        'bar' => true,
        'valid' = true,
    );
    // parse the string
    parse_str($arg_string, $parse_into);
    // return only the valid arguments
    return array_intersect_key($parse_into,$valid_arguments);

}
```

`baz` will be dropped because it is not listed in `$valid_arguments`. So for this call:

```
print_r(exampleParseArgs('foo=20&bar=strike&baz=50'));
```

Results:

```
Array
(
    [foo] => 20
    [bar] => strike
)
```

Additionally, you can browse the Wordpress [Source code here](http://phpxref.com/xref/wordpress/wp-includes/category-template.php.source.html#l425), and of course by downloading it from wordpress.org. Looks like they do something very similar.

Answer (score 6):

parse_str() should do what you want: http://www.php.net/parse_str